# How to delete index with %{} in the name opensearch

Tags: logstash, kibana, opensearch

Unfortunately I had in my logstash `logs-%{somefield}`, now it made more than one index with `%{somefield}` in them, which `Kibana` does not like and gives back 400s if I try and do any request to them. How can you escape these characters?

Comment: Have you checked https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-how-to-delete-index-containing-character/27647/2?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Don't use % while sending request instead use "*" character before the name like:

✖ DELETE /%{record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']}-2022.09.06

✔ DELETE /*.{record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']}-2022.09.06